# Referencing external .jar libraries in ant to build a Android java jar

Tags: java, android, ant, jar, build.xml

(I am new to ant and I've scoured the web for solutions to this, but none of them seem to work for me.)

I am trying to reference an external .jar library in building with ant. But, I receive errors such as: `package [name] does not exist`, next to the `import [name]` statement in the .java file

In my build.xml, I have the following line, which references the folder where the external jar is stored:

`<property name="lib.dir" value="libs"/>`

When I remove references to the external jar, ant builds. Right now, it just seems like ant is unable to find the external libraries, and **I am not sure how to update the build.xml properly to reference these libraries.**

Answer (score 1):

If you need jars included in your compilation, you can do something like:

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${local.build.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5" classpathref="base.classpath" debug="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this property entry and rebuilding. I have always had external library jars and it is always sufficient to add them in libs folder to get everything building successfully.

The reason why this property entry might be failing you is: the auto-generated `build.xml` references another build file in the android sdk tools folder. This other build file knows how to reference the `libs` folder of the project you are currently building, but from its perspective the path is not simply `libs`.

Comment: I am actually referencing multiple .jar files in different directories.. and also in libs

Comment: @ina: what stops you from putting them all in libs folder. Please describe your case a bit more into detail so that I could help.